# Handle HTTP Errors globally in angular

Tags: angular, http-error

I am working in **http error handling**. I have written error handling in each component which is not a good coding practice. So I have decided to write a common http error handling globally. I have searched for it, I have come across `http-interceptor` concept, I think there exists better way to handle the **HTTP** errors. What I have tried in each component is below Instead of that I need a global method. I already have http-interceptor file and the code is I am pasting below.

**component.ts:**

```
this.serviceName.methodName().catch(err => {
  console.log("Something went wrong with the request, please try again.");
  return Observable.throw(err.message.toUpperCase() || 'API_ERROR');
}).subscribe((res) => {
   console.log(res);
},
 error=>{
    this.openSnackBar('danger', "Something went wrong with the request, please try again.");
 });
```

**http-interceptor:**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class HttpErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
constructor() { }

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(tap(
        event => event instanceof HttpResponse ? 'succeeded' : '',
        err => 'failed'
    ))
 }
}
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: [Read the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses), nothing explains interceptors better than it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(tap(
      event => event instanceof HttpResponse ? 'succeeded' : '',
      err => {
        this.openSnackBar('danger', "Something went wrong with the request, please try again.");
      }
    ))
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I already have an http-interceptor file, please check my answer again. Please suggest where to write the 'error' code from your answer in my http-interceptor file.

Comment: Getting error after adding your code like `ERROR in src/app/services/common/httperror.interceptor.ts(15,13): error TS2345: Argument of type '(error: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => void'.`